# ci and apply tags in MathJax

Tags: math, mathml, mathjax

I have some mathml markup inside web (html) pages. When I try to use mathjax (from the cdn source) it fails on *apply* and *ci* tags. Does any solution exists, or should I make some configuration changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax only implements Presentation MathML, not Content MathML.  I am told that you can use an XSLT translation to convert Content to Presentation MathML, though I don't know how that is done.

Comment: i've found the appropriate transformation in open source. It can be found here: http://www.w3.org/Math/XSL/Overview-tech.html by the name ctop.xslt

Answer (score 0):

xlstproc installation: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/InstallingAProcessor.html
xlst stylesheets: https://www.w3.org/Math/XSL/Overview-tech.html

transformation via console:

```
xsltproc STYLESHEET.xslt input.xml > output.xml
```